# What is the benchmark metrics for performance test for any application by using Jmeter?

Tags: performance-testing

can u pls any one give suggestions about benchmark metrics i.e average time, Throughput, 90th percentile values for any websites like industry standards meant that any application wouldnt exceeds these values.
i.e 
default Average time =3 sec

default throughput and 90th percentile values??

Comment: 1 - "any application", by definition, it's a very broad category, therefore, not so informative. 2 - Any "industry standards" will be secondary in relation to YOUR context - information is only useful when targeting a problem, not a idealization: Be careful of the Nirvana Fallacy. I would suggest to edit the question with information about your problem, otherwise I would suggest closing due "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

As systems become faster and faster this industry standard/benchmark is becoming faster. 
Also I think it is not standardized.

The 3 seconds was a usabilty speed metric, as the brain would start wondering of if actions would take longer then 3 seconds. Which could result in loss of convertion. Now a days with the mobile generation this is probably lowered to 1-2 seconds.

The benchmark of performance is what your users expect. Do user research.

Answer (score 1):

There are no industry standards, there are [non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) and/or [service level agreements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) which might be different from project to project.

Certain systems are fine with jobs which fit overnight, certain systems require real-time responses, some calculations especially associated with space science or bioinformatics can run for years.

From JMeter perspective you can use i.e. [Duration Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps/) to automatically mark samplers which duration exceeds specified threshold as failed.

When it comes to generating [JMeter Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) there are following properties which you can use to define baselines for response times:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=500
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold=1500
```

Amend them according to your application specifics.